# Custom Login Page for SharePoint Using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint, jquery-mobile

I want to create one Login.aspx page with some custom theme. I am planning to use Jquery mobile for whole application so everything I have to do using Javascript.

How we can write javascript function for login to sharepoint site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice walkthrough on [implementing custom login page for SharePoint FBA](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/08/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page-for.html). So, you will have your own `login.aspx` page and you can use jquery mobile there.

Comment: Is It's possible with Windows Authentication.

Comment: FBA supports active directory as one of authentication providers, so it should be possible.